# Как оптимизировать сет в буферный массив?

Tags: javascript, оптимизация, webgl

Есть вопрос по оптимизации кода.

Цель понять как уменьшить объем кода в Example 1, без значительного уменьшения  производительности.

[Branchmark](https://jsben.ch/OsKbY)

Setup:

```
let data1={line:new Float32Array(50000)}
let data2={line:new Float32Array(50000)}


function setBuffer(name, figure_num, data_p){

  let num = 5 * figure_num
  let buffer_array = data1[name]
  for (let i = 0, l = data_p.length; i < l; i++) {
    buffer_array[num + i] = data_p[i];
  }
}
```

Example 1:

```
let pt1=[1,2]
let pt2=[3,4]
let status=5
for(let i=0;i<10000;i++){
  let buffer_array = data2['line']
  let num = 5*i;
  buffer_array[num+0] = pt1[0];
  buffer_array[num+1] = pt1[1];
  buffer_array[num+2] = pt2[0];
  buffer_array[num+3] = pt2[1];
  buffer_array[num+4] = status;

}
```

Example 2:

```
let pt1=[1,2]
let pt2=[3,4]
let status=5

for(let i=0;i<10000;i++){
  setBuffer('line', i, [pt1[0],pt1[1],pt2[0],pt2[1],status])
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: соберите всё предварительно в массив из пяти элементов и запустите цикл по нему(или может там есть копирование куска буфера)

Comment: это пример иллюстрирует часть алгоритма, который есть в реальном проекте, что бы исследовать производительно этой части алгоритма.  конечно в реальном проекте нету на столько последовательного цикла, и данные на каждой итерации разные приходят.

Comment: Значит собирайте шаблон для копирования на каждой итерации) Получится как второй пример, только без вызова функции

Comment: Входные данные приходят в виде figure_num data_p(данные уникальные, точки  типа float). Шаблон как такого нету.

Comment: Подобные требования нужно писать в вопросе, а не в комментариях. Что за figure_num? Пользовательский тип?

Comment: Спасибо, буду учитывать. figure_num - номер фигуры.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115407/discussion-between-anthony-v-and-vp-arth).

Answer (score 0):

```js
let pt1=[1,2]
let pt2=[3,4]
let status=5
let N = 5; // 10000
const data2 = {
 line: new Float32Array(5*N),
};
for(let i=0;i<N;i++){
  data2.line.set([pt1[0],pt1[1],pt2[0],pt2[1],status], 5 * i);
}
console.log(data2)
```

Хотя, при записи сэмпла в 5 элементов TypedArray.set вряд ли что-то выиграет у прямого доступа)

Мне кажется, если это стало действительно узким местом в вашем приложении, стоит посмотреть на какой-нибудь WebAssembly или, если дело происходит не в браузере, то на другой высокопроизводительный инструмент =)